# How to obtain GraphQL access token on local XM Cloud

Tags: graphql, xm-cloud

I want to use the GraphQL playground on my local instance of XM Cloud. The URL is `https://xmcloudcm.localhost/sitecore/api/authoring/graphql/ide/`.

My understanding is that in order for this to work, the playground must be enabled, and an access token must be generated.

I added `Sitecore_GraphQL_ExposePlayground: "true"` to my `docker-compose.override.yml` to enable the playground and I can load the GraphQL Playground in my browser but without the access token, no queries will work.

[image: GraphQL Playground]

This guide ([Walkthrough: Enabling and authorizing requests to the Authoring and Management API](https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/walkthrough--enabling-and-authorizing-requests-to-the-authoring-and-management-api.html)) provides the instructions for how to get a token, but I haven't been successful in getting it to work.

I always get some variation of

```
{
    "error": "access_denied",
    "error_description": "Unauthorized"
}
```

```
Error while getting client credentials token: Unauthorized
```

[image: error when running command]

[image: error in POSTMAN]

Working through the replacements that the guide mentions:

- `<authority-url>`: `endpoints.xmCloud.authority` value from the `.sitecore/user.json` file.

  - In my case this value is `https://auth.sitecorecloud.io/`
- `<your-client-id>`: `endpoints.xmCloud.clientId` value from the `.sitecore/user.json file`.

  - In my case this value is `Chixxxxxxxxxxxxxxv7`
- `<your-client-secret>`: `endpoints.xmCloud.clientSecret` value from the `.sitecore/user.json` file.

  - My `.user.json` file **contains no such key or value**, so I used a client secret value that I found in the `.env` file that was generated for me: `SITECORE_FedAuth_dot_Auth0_dot_ClientSecret=xjQlxxxxxxxxxxxxx-3j-vxxxxxxxxxQ`

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things here, There are two types of API

**1) Preview API** - Which what you are referring to which has a URL https://xmcloudcm.localhost/sitecore/api/authoring/graphql/ide for this to work, you will have to pass `sc_apikey` header parameter with the value of the API key (ITEM GUID) you created inside your sitecore instance on the path `/system/settings/services/api keys/<your api key item>`

**2) Delivery API** - Which has a universal URL https://edge.sitecorecloud.io//api/graphql/ide with the end point https://edge.sitecorecloud.io/api/graphql/v1 which can query for your published content on experience edge

as in your case you want to use a preview URL, you are not passing any header values, and `{ "authorization":"brere token" }` is not the right syntax, may be you got confused in the documentation, to get the API key you might need to get JWT token and from it, you get the API key, but here for preview API, it's just the item of your Sitecore under the path I mentioned, you pass GUID like below in header

[image]

And the below switch is for administration API like management and authoring API, so it should only be enabled if you want to `CREATE/DELETE` items from graphQL but I think you only want to fetch so turn this `OFF`

> Sitecore_GraphQL_ExposePlayground: "true"

Answer (score 1):

Do let me know if you are still facing issues, it seems there are changes you will need to do if you want to use authoring APIs

First of all the browser should have the following URL

```
https://<<Your cm host>>/sitecore/api/authoring/graphql/ide/
```

If you get document not found, you will have to turn on graph QL playground, but I can see you already are able to open the IDE so that is sorted

**Now when you hit the above URL in a browser, it opens up IDE with the wrong URL, change that URL to the following and hit enter (not in the browser URL but in the IDE right-hand side of the history tab)**

```
https://<<your cm host>>/sitecore/api/authoring/graphql/v1/
```

**NOTE**: that SLASH at the end is important too, and by default, IDE generates the wrong URL

Now, you will need to authorize the IDE so it can make calls, and for it you will need to use client id and secret from XM Cloud "Automation Clent" option, it will create ClientId, and Secret for you

Now use them in following command first

```
dotnet sitecore cloud login --client-credentials --client-id <your-client-id> --client-secret <your-client-secret> --allow-write true --xmcloudhost <your-xmcloud-host> --authority <authority-url> --audience <audience-url>
```

upon successful login, fire the below command

```
curl --location --request POST '<authority-url>/oauth/token' --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode 'client_id=<your-client-id>' --data-urlencode 'client_secret=<your-client-secret>' --data-urlencode 'audience=<audience-url>' --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

Now you will get a token, pass this token as following in header

```
{
  "Authorization":"Bearer <<token you got above>>"
}
```

I have mentioned all the steps on https://daivagnananavati.blogspot.com/2023/04/xm-cloud-10-steps-of-graphql-mutations.html  see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

On your local CM and the preview end point on your XM Cloud CM, you use the guid of your `/system/settings/services/api keys/<your api key item>` as the api key. If you look in your `.env` file you should see the value.